# AngularJS automatically select/deselect radio button

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button

I have AngularJs code where i want a radio button to be automatically selected and another radio button unselected whenever a user selects a checkbox and then a specific option from a dropdown. [image]

So from the picture above, if a user selects the pacing checkbox then selects evenly from the dropdown, the 'Specific timezone' radio button should be automatically selected. Depending of the order of the button selections, there is also times when if pacing and evenly are selected first then the Dayparting checkbox is selected, the 'Users timezone' radio button will be selected and evenly will no longer be selected in the dropdown

```html
<div class="radio radio-primary radio-specific">
  <input name="timezone" id="specific_time" type="radio" checked="checked"
         ng-click="specificTimezone = true;$ctrl.specificTimezoneRadioClicked()">
  <label for="specific_time">Specific timezone</label>
</div>


<input ng-if="!$ctrl.isDeliveryPacingFeatureEnabled"
    name="timezone" id="user_time" type="radio" checked="checked"
    value="viewer"
    ng-model="$ctrl.deal.deal_settings.dayparting.timezone"
    ng-click="specificTimezone = false">
```

I use the below line to disable the 'User timezone' radio button

ng-disabled="$ctrl.pacingEnabled() && $ctrl.evenlyPacingEnabled()"

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ng-change` You can read the [documentation here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" style="width:25%" ng-model="selectedVal" ng-change="changeOption()">
  <option ng-repeat="lookup in optionsList" ng-value="lookup">
    {{lookup}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Hope this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/aawm8jog/1/) will give you a head start.

Comment: Thank you , i will give this a try now